# Me dice que el valor que estoy llamando es undefined en json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, java-ee

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me dice que es undefined el nombre de la variable que estoy pidiendo
Jquery, pero le pongo console.log(data) y me devuelve el arreglo completo y con sus variables

```
$(function () {
array_producto = [];
$.ajax({
    url: "ofertas_guardadas",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    error: function () {
        alert("Error");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function (i, item)
        {
            var json = item.nombre;
            alert(json);
        });
    }
});
```

servlet

```
 @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    HttpSession sesion = request.getSession(false);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    int id_consumidor = Integer.parseInt(sesion.getAttribute("id_consumidor").toString());
    String producto;
    String nombre, precio_oferta, precio_normal, id, ruta;
    JSONArray lista = new JSONArray();
    productoFacade.oferta_guardadas(id_consumidor);
    for (Producto p : productoFacade.oferta_guardadas(id_consumidor)) {
        nombre = p.getNombreProducto();
        id = p.getIdProducto().toString();
        precio_normal = p.getPrecioNormal().toString();
        precio_oferta = p.getPrecioOferta().toString();
        ruta = p.getRutaImagen();
        producto = new StringBuilder("{").
                append("\"nombre\":\"" + nombre + "\",").
                append("\"id\":\"" + id + "\",").
                append("\"precio_normal\":\"" + precio_normal + "\",").
                append("\"precio_oferta\":\"" + precio_oferta + "\",").
                append("\"ruta\":\"" + ruta + "\"").
                append("}").toString();
        lista.put(producto);
    }
    out.print(lista.toString());
}
```

También probé esto

```
        success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function (i, item)
        {
            console.log(data[i].nombre)
            var json = JSON.parse(data[i].nombre);
            alert(json);
        });
```

En esta imagen sale lo que imprime el console.log()
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchos programan un json así `{
    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh",
    ],
    [
      "Ashton Cox",
      "Junior Technical Author",
      "San Francisco",   ]
    /* Etc.... */
}` pero a veces hay que ponerle nombre `{
  "data": [
    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh",   ],[
      "Ashton Cox",
      "Junior Technical Author",
      "San Francisco",
    ]
    /* Etc.... */
  ]
}` creo que ese es tu problema, falta el nombre en este caso "data"

Comment: en la imagen que pones parece que te faltan los corchetes `[ ]`

Comment: pega el json aqui http://json2java.azurewebsites.net/ y si te genera las clases esta correcto, y si no las genera tienes error en el json

Comment: De acuerdo con esas imagenes, item es un string. Como un string no tiene propiedad nombre, entonces item.nombre eso es undefined.

Comment: dale `var item = JSON.parse(data);` y entonces `console.log(item.nombre);`

Comment: Actualicé la publicación

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a todos por los consejos, pero no pude hacerlo de esa forma, así que busqué una alternativa y todo salió de maravilla. Les dejo la solución, por si a alguien le sirve.
Saludos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    HttpSession sesion = request.getSession(false);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    int id_consumidor = Integer.parseInt(sesion.getAttribute("id_consumidor").toString());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Producto producto = new Producto();
    List<Producto> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    productoFacade.oferta_guardadas(id_consumidor);
    for (Producto p : productoFacade.oferta_guardadas(id_consumidor)) {
        producto.setNombreProducto(p.getNombreProducto());
        producto.setIdProducto(p.getIdProducto());
        producto.setPrecioNormal(p.getPrecioNormal());
        producto.setPrecioOferta(p.getPrecioOferta());
        producto.setRutaImagen(p.getRutaImagen());
        lista.add(producto);
    }
    String json = gson.toJson(lista);
    out.print(json);
}
```

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ofertas_guardadas",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/gson",
    error: function () {

        alert("Error");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item)
        {
            var json = item;
            console.log(json.idProducto);
            console.log(json.nombreProducto);
            console.log(json.precioNormal);
            console.log(json.precioOferta);
            console.log(json.rutaImagen);
            alert(json.nombreProducto);
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que convertir la variable `item` a json para poder acceder a las propiedades utilizando el metodo `JSON.parse()`:

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
     var json = JSON.parse(item).nombre;
     alert(json);
});
```

Aunque parezca un json, en realidad cada elemento del array `data` es un string que contiene un valor en formato json y como un string no tiene una propiedad llamada `nombre`, te muestra `Undefined`.

Comment: No me está parseando :(